# Does a .JAR file not perform a checksum check when executed?

Tags: java, jar, checksum, crc

I was testing something along the lines of:
- Alter the content of a JAR file (via Notepad++)
- Save and run it

As JAR files are basically just ZIP archives, I assumed that before the JVM actually runs the JAR file, the checksums are being verified. But that was not the case, the JAR file was executed and an exception was thrown, that something was missing.

When extracting with 7zip for example, a CRC error is reported. I expected the same behavior when running it.

Am I missing something? Or is there actually no checksum check performed before/while running a JAR file?

Comment: whenever you mention a thrown exception or occured error, please also share the error and in case of an exception the name of the exception with error message and if possible at least the first part of the stacktrace

Comment: I would have done that, but as the exception doesn't matter at all (because it would change depending on which part or how much of the content is deleted). The exception has nothing to do with any CRC check, and does only mention that a method couldn't be called due to missing data. (e.g. here: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) The main focus is just on the fact that the JAR file is being executed without a CRC check, as I assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer**:

As long as you do not use an old Java version <= 7 that misses a fix for this [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4879507) and  as long as you do not use a custom ClassLoader the CRC of each zip entry within a JAR file is verified when a JAR is loaded from classpath.

**The long answer** (by example for Java 8, I'm not aware of any known regression bugs in newer Java versions):

Java's URLClassLoader (default system classloader in Java 8) uses class
[sun.net/www/protocol/jar/JarURLConnection](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/JarURLConnection.java) to read JAR files from URLs.

This class uses [sun/net/www/protocol/jar/URLJarFile](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/URLJarFile.java) which is a sub class of
[java/util/zip/ZipFile](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/aa318070b27849f1fe00d14684b2a40f7b29bf79/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipFile.java). This class calls the read method of a [java/util/zip/ZipInputStream](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/aa318070b27849f1fe00d14684b2a40f7b29bf79/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.java) to read zip entries.

The ZipInputStream class verifies CRC for uncompressed Zip entries [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/aa318070b27849f1fe00d14684b2a40f7b29bf79/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.java#L219) and for compressed ZIP entries [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/aa318070b27849f1fe00d14684b2a40f7b29bf79/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.java#L392). In case of a corrupted zip entry (there's a CRC for each Zip Entry and not for the whole ZIP file) a ZipException is thrown.

---

You get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError because the JAR file cannot be loaded. There has to be an error before. I haven't checked the error handling, but I guess the ZipException is somewhere catched and logged or maybe added as cause to the NoClassDefFoundError. Since you neither share your JAR file nor any error output its hard to verify. Another possibility is that only the single corrupted ZIP Entry is skipped and others are loaded - I hadn't the time to dig more into the error handling, if you are interested have a look on it, I linked all the mentioned classes to the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into the info you provided.  I tried it again, and altered data in different areas of the JAR file in Notepad and got many different outcomes. Sometimes, JVM does actually show an error "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile ...", but in other cases the JAR file just runs normally or shows exceptions like NoClassDefFoundError. To me it was just weird, because I thought once I altered ANY data in the JAR, this should be checked.

Comment: If you use 7-ZIP in combination with Notepad++ to edit your JAR file, ensure that the ZIP file is not opened in an other program while you edit it. 7-Zip makes copies of the ZIP file content which it has to synchronize with the original file. I already ran into situations, where this sync did not work properly, without any errors. In my case I had the same ZIP file open in another instanceof 7-Zip  ;-)